# Limit number of tickets available in Google form

Tags: google-forms, google-forms-api

I need to set up a **Google form** for an event that has **30 available seats**.

I thought about **limiting the number of submissions to 30**, but then people can order only one seat per submission.

Is there any way to set the form up to have a total of 30 seats available, where the user can order for example up to five seats with each submission and when the 30 seats are all booked, the form will respond with a message that the event is fully booked?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a general question regarding google forms that would be better suited on superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can download an add-ons named FormLimiter and use it to limit availability of the ticket, but I don't think you can add 5 seats in one submission and consider it as the availability, one passive way to solve this issue is to not provide no.of seats option in the form but give the option for multiple responses.

Here are the steps to follow:-

1.Step 1: Hit the three dot button in the top right corner and then got to Get add-ons

[image]
2.Step 2: search formlimiter and click the add-ons named "FormLimiter"

[image]

3. Step 3: Install the add-ons and a new popup opens with the submission limiter, here you can adjust and limit the availability to 30. Also Ensure that "Limit to 1 Response" option in "setting" of the form is disabled.

[image]
For more detailed explanation : https://form-publisher.com/blog/how-to-limit-responses-in-google-forms-easily/#step-3-select-%E2%80%98set-limit%E2%80%99

Hope the steps above Helped, If there are any better ways will let you know immediately! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check this out :).