# Forms-Sheets Students automatically change seats in limited workshops, based on conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

There are 75 students split in 2 groups (36 and 39 students). There are 2 workshops with a max of 30 participants (mainly, group 1 goes to workshop 1 and group 2 goes to workshop 2). This is because most of the times, not all of the 75 students are coming to the workshops, so we don't always need to have 3 workshops (25 participants/workshop). However, in certain circumstances, some students can opt for changing the workshop that they want to participate in.

So, from the students POV: They submit the form:

- (Section 1 - Name and group.
- Section 2 (for group 1) - "Are you participating in Ws1?" - "Yes"/"No"/"Change".
- Section 3 (for group 2) - the same as section 1, but with Ws2.)

Inside the Sheet i have made 3 tabs:

- Form Responses 1,
- Workshop 1 (In A1 i have `=query('Form Responses 1'!$A:F,"Select * Where C='Group 1'")`, and
- Workshop 2 (In A1 `=query('Form Responses 1'!$A:F,"Select * Where C='Group 2'")`.

Please help me with a formula or a script so that when (i.e.) student 3 from group 1 selects "Change", he can participate in workshop 2 ONLY IF student 5 from group 2 selects "No" (so Student 3 can take his seat) OR student 6 from group 2 selects "Change" (so they can switch places) automatically, based on those conditions). I need these conditions so that students from a group don't occupy the other's workshop seats unless a student originally assigned to that workshop declares his seat free.

I have tried this formula and it doesn't work: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D:D="Yes", query(A:E)"Yes", "") + IF(('Workshop 2'!E:E="Change") * (D:D="No") + ('Workshop 2'!E:E="Change") * (D:D="Change"), query('Workshop 2'!(A:E)), ""))`.

Also, please help me with formLimiter: I want to change the availability of form answers, based on # of participants submitted to a workshop. (i.e. if Group 1 answers of "Yes" + Group 2 answers of "Change" = 30, then in forms, Group 1 can no longer answer "Yes" and group 2 can no longer answer "Change". And vice-versa for Workshop 2. Also, if both workshops reach 30 participants, i want another option to appear in the "your group" question: "Group 3", which, if chosen, automatically sends to another section with Yes/No/Change for workshop 3.

Here is the link to Forms and Sheets folder (with editor access):
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lgter_-dBwWdBjc7OCCDGruCHSmfJhTC?usp=sharing

Comment: `unless a student originally assigned to that workshop declares his seat free.` Isn't it the case that such a student might not submit a form at all OR will not submit the form until the last minute. In that case, the availability of places in the Group 2 w/shop for Group 1 students (and vice versa) can't be known until the last student in each Group has submitted their form.

Comment: For the ignorant amongst us (that's me, folks), `formLimiter` is a Forms add-on. Related question: [Limit number of tickets available in Google form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77184208/1330560)

Comment: @Tedinoz, you're right. Still, i can't think of another way of students not "stealing" seats from the other group. For now, students just exchange seats via Whatsapp. The probem i've encountered is something like this:
Student 1 (Gr1): i want to change seats.
Student 2 (Gr2): I'm interested.
Student 3 (Gr2): I'm interested, also.
Then, student 2 and student 3 fight over who should deserve the exchange.
I'd like to make this exchange automatic, based on those conditions, since i can't think of a better way to satisfy everybody

Comment: I think a first-come, first-served basis would be fair. But there are controls to consider. for example, a student who submits a “Change” MUST previously submitted a “Yes”; there are a host of these “issues”. But I need to make something crystal clear - Google Forms does **NOT** allow you to do this validation in real-time. Forms can’t dynamically access Sheets data prior to form submission. All the matching (and notification) of “changes” would have to happen in Sheets, though you could then process the  change by script.

Comment: I think i understand what you're explaining about forms. Inside the forms, based on the group selected, it opens the section for the workshop. If a student selects gr 2, he answers Yes/No/Change only on workshop 2, and then he submits. So he doesn't have to submit a Yes response before his Change response.
I'd like to have a formula that copies in a Ws1 sheet students with Gr1+Yes AND students with Gr2+Change ONLY IF there are students with gr1+No OR gr1 + Change.
If students change their mind prior to submission, then i'd manually edit the sheet.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m unable to understand the question and the various permutations of “Form submissions” by student and Group. Im unable to offer an answer to this question.